# Cannot get ng-controller to work in angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, ng-app

I've just started learning web development on my own, and I've run into an issue where either my entire app or just a controller just won't cooperate.

In `prototype.js`, I declare the app:

```
    var cds = angular.module('cds', ['ngRoute']);

    cds.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'appCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'partials/login.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
      });

    cds.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-login';
        $scope.list = [
            {name: 'One', description: 'I'},
            {name: 'Two', description: 'II'},
            {name: 'Three', description: 'III'},
            {name: 'One More', description: 'Extra'}
        ];
    }]);
```

In my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app='cds'>
    <head>
        <title>References</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/prototype.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        @import url("styles.css");
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    </head> 

    <body ng-controller='appCtrl' onload="align()" onresize="align()">
        {{ pageClass }}
        <div ng-view></div>
        <div id="dropdown">
            <button class="drop-btn">Options</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#/body_diagram"><img src="img/header.menu.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

For some reason, `{{ pageClass }}` won't even display the value I assigned to it in the controller, let alone `ng-view` elements. Before, I had followed a very old routing tutorial where the app was declared using just `angular.module('myApp', ...)`, and all controllers made as individual functions independent from the angular app, and everything worked fine for me. However, after jumping from angular 1.0.7 to 1.5.8 (it's a long story, and a newbie mistake), I tried updating the style and cleaning my code up, and this is what happened. I feel like I'm missing something very basic here.

Edit:

Turns out I forgot to include ng-route. Derp. Now everything's working perfectly. Thanks all!

Comment: A fiddle would be nice

Comment: Is there any error message(s) on your debugger window?(In chrome it will be on the console in developer tools window).

Comment: Sorry, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/26672/. I'm just baffled by how I can't even get 'page-login' to appear on the screen instead of `{{ pageClass }}`.

Comment: warun26 you're freaking awesome it turns out I forgot to include the ng-route dependency! Never knew about the developer console before this. I'm sure it'll be extremely useful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the `ngRoute` module.  You can link to it through the CDN:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/26677/) with the added dependency.

Answer (score 0):

hey be sure to include ngRoute, and maybe put the script includes at the bottom of body... got your fiddle to work by doing so